# Plugin/API for flutter for making a voice changing app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to make an application which changes the recorded voice into a different sounding voice for ex. Robotic voice, thin voice(high pitched/childlike), heavy voice, funny voice etc.
I already have the recording functionality handled with a plugin, I only want a voice conversion functionality.
Please suggest some plugins/API's compatible with flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything like this exist in dart but you can use C plugin to do this using Dart:ffi (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop)

Comment: Hi I am not able to find any plugins for voice changing in any language.Could you please send some links or how to find them? Even individual voice filters would work.

Comment: I found this https://gitlab.com/soundtouch/soundtouch, but I never tried to do this so I can't help you with that